# Java 8 Streams: conditionals to avoid repetition?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

is there a way to achieve something similar like my code below, without having to avoid repeating myself while also keeping the processing low?

```
    List<String> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    alist.add("hello");
    alist.add("hello2");

    if(verbose) {
        alist.stream()
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .forEach(/*dostuff*/);
    }
    else {
        alist.stream().forEach(/*dostuff*/);
    }
```

As seen above, I'm forced to repeat myself by handling the stream in either the if or else case which looks kind of ugly if the stream becomes a bit longer.

There's the other option which in my opinion looks cleaner but should be worse performance wise as it compares the verbose-boolean for every item in the list.

```
    List<String> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    alist.add("helllo");
    alist.add("hello2");

    alist.stream()
            .peek(this::printVerbose)
            .forEach(/*dostuff*/);

}


private void printVerbose(String v) {
    if(verbose) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```

}

Comment: that has little do with streams thought, simply take the variables outside the if/else - common sense, in a way. some people, like me - might find whatever you already have in place pretty readable; the only problem is that if you *later* will need changes, you will most probably need to make them in two places - and that is easy to forget

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
    Stream<Integer> stream = alist.stream();
    if(verbose) {
        stream = stream
                .peek(System.out::println);
    }
    stream.forEach(/*dostuff*/);
```

Comment: Depending on personal preference one can remove the curly braces as well to make it more compact.

Answer (score 2):

There's another way that checks the flag only once, when creating the `Consumer` to be passed to `peek`. You need the following method:

```
public static <T> Consumer<? super T> logIfNeeded(boolean verbose) {
    return verbose ? System.out::println : t -> { };
}
```

Then, in your stream pipeline:

```
alist.stream()
        .peek(logIfNeeded(verbose))
        .forEach(/*dostuff*/);
```

The difference with your 2nd approach is that the flag is not checked for every element; the action is chosen eagerly, when the static method is called at stream pipeline declaration.